# Odd error connecting to a postgresql database

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.askyb.com/cpp/c-postgresql-example/), but I get some errors that I don't quite understand. I'm pretty much just have 2 functions, one for closing it, and one for opening it. I'm clueless as to why these errors are here.

DatabaseWriter.h:

```
#ifndef FILEPARSER_H
#define FILEPARSER_H

#include "DatabaseWriter.h"

using namespace std;

class DatabaseWriter
{
private:

public:
    void CloseConn(PGconn *conn);
    PGconn DatabaseWriter::*ConnectDB ();

    DatabaseWriter ();

};

#endif
```

DatabaseWriter.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include "libpq-fe.h"
#include "DatabaseWriter.h"

using namespace std;

const char* CONNECTIONSTRING = "user=postgres password=superman dbname=poker hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432";

void DatabaseWriter::CloseConn (PGconn *conn)
{
    PQfinish(conn);
    getchar();
    exit(1);
}

PGconn DatabaseWriter::*ConnectDB ()
{
    PGconn *conn = NULL;

    // Make a connection to the database
    conn = PQconnectdb(CONNECTIONSTRING);

    // Check to see that the backend connection was successfully made
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        printf("Connection to database failed");
        CloseConn(conn);
    }

    printf("Connection to database - OK\n");

    return conn;
}
```

I defined CloseConn earlier myself, so it shouldn't be undefined.

[image: Error 1]

The return type of ConnectDB is PGconn, conn is a PGconn, so I don't see why it shouldn't return it.

[image: Error 2]

Obviously there are things I'm blatantly looking over, so thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `DatabaseWriter::` inside the class declaration, only in the definition. I also suggest you take a closer look at that definition, especially where the `*` is in it.